# Stand-still current of servo motor

Tags: current, servo

Is the stand-still current the maximum current that a servo motor draws?

Is it logical to say that it is the counterpart of full-load current of an induction motor?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are many different types of motors used in servo systems whereas ‘induction motor’ is reasonably specific.  I would expect for a servo system that the hold current is based on the load. If there is little load, then the hold current is small but as the system detects any change from the expected position it will attempt to compensate. In answer to you question I would say No.  the comparison between a servo system and FLC of an induction motor is not valid.

Comment: I am not sure if "Stand Still current" is a well-defined term. If you saw it in a document, it might help to share a link to the document, or a photograph if you are unable to link to it. I think more context is required to answer the question.

Comment: Servo systems may use a variety of control laws so it's not guaranteed, but likely max current can be achieved when you hold it to one extreme, while ordering it to the opposite limit.

Comment: Are you asking about stepper motor? Because the whole point of a stepper motor is to hold so holding is its "normal" current, totally opposite to an induction motor.

Answer (score 1):

The "maximum" current will often occur when the motor is stalled. This could be some moments leading up-to the stall, after the stall, or at failure (when things begin to heat up fast and it breaks). You will often find graphs or tables of these currents with respect to load and voltage in the data sheets.

But in most data sheets this is referred to as the "stall current". I have not seen the term "stand-still current" used often, if at all. Perhaps by "stand-still" current they meant "idle current"? In that case, idle current draw would be the current while the motor is simply running without any load. Also remember that the current draw is going to depend entirely on the voltage supplied to the motor. See ["Ohm's law"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)